# Using Mysql to select values from different tables with different names as credit and debit and calculate balance

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get values from different tables with different column names and select it as a common name that I could make a balance calculation.
Something like that:

Table 1 (credit)

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| ID_company|  date_table1 |  credit_table1|
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
|         1 |   2017-08-19 |            50 | 
|         1 |   2017-08-19 |           250 |
|         1 |   2017-08-20 |             0 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
```

Table 2 (credit)

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| ID_company|  date_table2 |  credit_table2|
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
|         1 |   2017-08-19 |           150 | 
|         1 |   2017-08-19 |            50 |
|         1 |   2017-08-19 |             0 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
```

Table 3 (debit)

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| ID_company|  date_table3 |   debit_table3|
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
|         1 |   2017-08-19 |            10 | 
|         1 |   2017-08-19 |            10 |
|         1 |   2017-08-20 |             0 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
```

Table 4 (debit)

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| ID_company|  date_table4 |   debit_table4|
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
|         1 |   2017-08-19 |            10 | 
|         1 |   2017-08-19 |            10 |
|         1 |   2017-08-20 |             0 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
```

Result

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------+
| ID_company|  date_grouped|   total_debit | total_credit | balance |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------+
|         1 |   2017-08-19 |            20 |          200 |     180 |
|         1 |   2017-08-19 |            20 |          300 |     280 | 
|         1 |   2017-08-20 |             0 |            0 |       0 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------+
```

The relation between the tables is the ID_company, but the column names are different and I need to calculate the credit, debit and balance from all tables grouped by date.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Edited it. Hope It could be more clearly now. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry about the date, gonna change it.

Comment: @VictorFaria the desired result is very strange is confusing and kinda mission impossible since you have multiple date numbers with same company id how do you now which debit belongs to which date since date is the same ?

Comment: So I need to group it all as a new variable like total_credit grouped by date. Just need to group by date and the ID_company needs to be the 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work, even if there is no entry for a given date in up to three tables.
Balance is per day, not accumulative.

It will not produce your example result, but I think there's an error in your example. Do you really need two rows for ID 1 and the same date?

```
SELECT 
    ID_company, 
    date_grouped, 
    sum(credit_table1) + sum(credit_table2) total_credits, 
    sum(debit_tabel3) + sum(debit_table4) total_debit, 
    sum(debit_tabel3) + sum(debit_table4)
        - (sum(credit_table1) + sum(credit_table2)) balance
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ID_Company, 
        date_table1 date_grouped, 
        credit_table1,
        0 credit_table2, 
        0 debit_table3, 
        0 debit_table4 
    FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT 
        ID_Company, 
        date_table2 date_grouped, 
        0 credit_table1, 
        credit_table2,
        0 debit_table3, 
        0 debit_table4 
    FROM table2
    UNION
    SELECT 
        ID_Company, 
        date_table3 date_grouped, 
        0 credit_table1, 
        0 credit_table2, 
        debit_table3,
        0 debit_table4 
    FROM table3
    UNION
    SELECT 
        ID_Company, 
        date_table4 date_grouped, 
        0 credit_table1, 
        0 credit_table2, 
        0 debit_table3,
        debit_table4
    FROM table4  
)
GROUP BY ID_company, date_grouped
```

Comment: I am not that in creating the best queries but this looks insane for the requested result.

Comment: This gave me an a Idea. Thank you.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Just dit it. Thank you.